# How to detect the 2D images using ARKit and RealityKit

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, arimageanchor

I want to detect the 2D images using **ARKit** and **RealityKit**. I don't want to use SceneKit because many implementations based on RealityKit. I couldn't find any examples detecting images on RealityKit. I referred https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/detecting_images_in_an_ar_experience sample code from apple. It uses Scenekit and `ARSCNViewDelegate`

```
let arConfiguration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
arConfiguration.planeDetection = [.vertical, .horizontal]
arConfiguration.isLightEstimationEnabled = true
arConfiguration.environmentTexturing = .automatic

if let referenceImages = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "sanitzer", bundle: nil) {
    arConfiguration.maximumNumberOfTrackedImages = 1
    arConfiguration.detectionImages = referenceImages
}
self.session.run(arConfiguration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
```

I have implemented `ARSessionDelegate` but not able to detect image?

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
    //how to capture image anchor?
}   
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
    //how to capture image anchor?
}
```

Apple has implemented `ARSCNViewDelegate` capture the detected images. What is the equivalent delegate for ARSCNViewDelegate in RealityKit? How to detect ARImageAnchor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `ARKit`/`RealityKit` project use the following code for `session()` instance methods:

```
import ARKit
import RealityKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSessionDelegate {

    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {

        guard let imageAnchor = anchors.first as? ARImageAnchor,
              let _ = imageAnchor.referenceImage.name
        else { return }

        let anchor = AnchorEntity(anchor: imageAnchor)

        // Add Model Entity to anchor
        anchor.addChild(model)

        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        arView.session.delegate = self
        resetTrackingConfig()
    }

    func resetTrackingConfig() {

        guard let refImg = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "Sub",
                                                                  bundle: nil)
        else { return }

        let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        config.detectionImages = refImg
        config.maximumNumberOfTrackedImages = 1

        let options = [ARSession.RunOptions.removeExistingAnchors,
                       ARSession.RunOptions.resetTracking]

        arView.session.run(config, options: ARSession.RunOptions(options))
    }
}
```

And take into consideration – a folder for reference images (in `.png` or `.jpg` format) must have an extension `.arresourcegroup`.

Comment: i am always getting AREnvironmentProbeAnchor but not ARImageAnchor. I am not getting Why?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Use my code, it works fine.

Comment: I tried checking it and it was still not working for AREnvironmentProbeAnchor.

Comment: @vrat2801, post your own question (with the code you wrote).